# unexpected d3.stack() output

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3's stack layout for the first time to produce a stream graph.

This code:

```
var w = 600,
    h = 350; 
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w])
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([h, 0])
//...
d3.csv("filePath", function(error, input)){
    var data = parseData(input);
    setDomains(data); //sets x and y domain values. These are return expected values
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h) //.attr("height", h*3) is used to produce second result
            .append("g")
            //.attr("transform", "translate(0, 250)"); is used to produce second result

   var stack = d3.layout.stack().offset("silhouette"),
       layers = stack(data);

   var area = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function (d, i) {return x(d.x);})
        .y0(function (d) {return y(d.y0);})
        .y1(function (d) {return y(d.y0 + d.y);});

    svg.selectAll(".layer")
        .data(layers)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "layer")
        .attr("d", function (d) {return area(d);})
        .style("fill", function (d, i) {return color(d[0].type);});
```

is giving me this output:

[image]

By increasing the height of the svg and translating the parent `g` down by 240px (see comments in code), I get my expected result: 
[image]

The scale of those images is a bit off - in reality, I'm getting the same graphic, but it's placed ~250 pixels higher than expected.

I'm trying to understand **why might that be?**

I can post `setDomains()` if needed, but my `x()` and `y()` functions are returning expected outputs for given inputs in debugging - i.e. a call to `y(maxDataVal)` returns `0`, as expected. I'm thinking this is related to something I'm not understanding about `stack()`, which hopefully is evident in the above.

Comment: Are you *sure* maxDataValue isn't just the max for a single series of data?

Comment: @Andrew - yep, that was my first thought too. Verified by checking the domain of `y()`

Comment: How could `setDomains(data)` possibly be computing the right domain extents if `data` gets transformed (via stacking) into `layers` and so has extents that are different than the global min & max of `data`?